# validator-class references to "xxx" that does not extend javax.faces.validator.Validator

Tags: validation, jsf

We're using JSF 1.2 / JBoss 4.2.3 GA/ IDE JBoss Developer Studio Version: 7.1.0.GA. I'm encountering a warning message when using a validator class declared as below in the faces-config.xml.

```
<validator>
    <validator-id>emailValidator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>com.afb.dda.relanceclient.jsf.bean.EmailValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

The warning message is:

> validator-class references to "com.afb.dda.relanceclient.jsf.bean.EmailValidator" that does not extend javax.faces.validator.Validator

My issue is similar as this link 
http://w3facility.org/question/validator-class-references-to-myvaidator-that-does-not-extend-javax-faces-validator-validator/ I tried the suggested solution but didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide us the code where the error shows up? You will receive a better answer if you are more specific in your questions. We have to guess what you did otherwise and it creates speculation, not solid answers.

Comment: This warning is not coming from JSF itself. It's coming from the editor you're using. If you're absolutely positive that it implements `Validator`, then it's the IDE's mistake and you can safely ignore it.

Comment: @BalusC When I try using a Ctrl+space to display the listed class it doesn't shows the emailValidator id. Is there a workaround to force this validator class on the xhtml file. Thanks.

Comment: Please answer the following questions with "Yes" or "No" only: 1) Does the given class implement `javax.faces.validator.Validator`? 2) Is it properly invoked when you ignore all IDE disturbance and build/deploy/run the project anyway? 3) Do you have any JSF API/impl JAR files in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: @BalusC 1) Yes 2) Yes  3) No  Just to add on C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\portal\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\jsf-libs directory found the 2 files under it. jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar

Comment: OK, then it's just an IDE-specific problem. Tell about the IDE make/version in the question and in the meanwhile, try updating to latest IDE version (or JSF-related plugin) to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Ok I'll try downloading the latest IDE version and see if the issue gone. Thanks BalusC.